# What has bigger priority ETag or Cache-Control?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control, etag, http-caching

If header has Cache-Control:no-cache and ETag, what has bigger priority? Is it possible that cache works in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not cached then it won't have the ETag to send back next time.